# Can't find specific address for specific customer by internal id

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to find the specific address by internal id from specific customer. Currently I'm trying to fetch 'address1' and 'address2' columns.

```
function getAddrById(addressid,invcustomerid) {
  try {
    var filters = new Array();
    filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'is', invcustomerid);

        var columns = new Array();
        columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('address1');

        var searchResult = nlapiSearchRecord('customer', null, filters , columns);
        debugger;

        if (!searchResult || searchResult.length < 1) {
            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'XML HEAD', 'not supported address');
            return;
        }

        if(searchResult) {
            for (var i = 0 ; i < searchResult.length; i++) {
            alert(searchResult[i].getValue('address1'));
        };
        };
    } catch(e) {
        nlapiLogExecution('ERROR', 'Try/catch error', e.message);
    }
}
```

... here I get all address subrecords for specific customer, but I want only one specified by internal id, not to list all associated addresses from the customer.

Answer (score 3):

`columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('addr1');`

should be:

`columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('address1');`

From your own link, you should be using the internal id from 'Search Columns' list at the bottom of the record, not "Fields".

Comment: That's right I just realize this. There is no error but no results. Do I need to specify the customer ID somewhere?

Comment: You aren't searching based on customer.  The internal ID in the filter is for the address record, not the customer. If you want a specific customer's address, it's probably best to start with a customer search.  Try building a search like you want in the UI, save it, then use nlapiLoadSearch to load the search somewhere and review the columns, filters, etc to reverse engineer how to create the appropriate search entirely in SS.

Comment: The task must be finished without Saved search. Okay thanks I'm still trying.

Comment: @SheaBrennan or use this excellent Chrome plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-search-export/gglbgdfbkaelbjpjkiepdmfaihdokglp